# Select both child item and its parent in QGraphicsFramework

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem

I've implemented a scene in my program using QGraphicsFramework.
So I have a shape (parent) and its anchor point (child) both `QGraphicsItem`.

```
Shape::Shape(QGraphicsItem *parent) :
    QGraphicsItem(parent)
{
    setFlags(ItemIsSelectable | ItemIsMovable | ItemSendsGeometryChanges);
    anchorPoint = new AnchorPoint(this);
    anchorPoint->setParentItem(this);
    anchorPoint->setVisible(false);
}
```

The anchor point item usually invisible. But when I select my shape I have to show its anchor point and accordingly to hide it when the shape loses selection.
So I've bound this action to itemChange:

```
QVariant Shape::itemChange(QGraphicsItem::GraphicsItemChange change, const QVariant &value)
{
    switch(change)
    {
        case QGraphicsItem::ItemSelectedChange:
            anchorPoint->setVisible(value.toBool());
        break;
    }
    return QGraphicsItem::itemChange(change, value);
}
```

But the problem appears when I want to move the anchor point. If I click it the shape loses focus and so hides its anchor point so I can't move it. Is there a way to select child item when its parent stays selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define your own `isSelected` property (and selection manager if multiple selection is needed) on top of what is provided by default, which set to true when the Shape is selected, and to false if either another Shape gets selected or you click the empty scene. The anchor point, not being a Shape, will not cause the parent Shape to get deselected when it is selected.

This way you can have selection in two contexts - what the scene considers selected, and what you consider selected. I've done this in QML and it is quite handy, however, I refer to the custom selection as focus, using handles of an object changes the selection but not the focus, which is useful for keyboard events with an extra dispatcher as well, because I assume you'd also want the Shape to be receiving keyboard events while the anchor point is being selected, rather than being received by the anchor.

Comment: Thanks, @ddriver. I've been thinking about this way. But I'm a bit annoying of that I'm going to implement some functionality that already implemented. I'm talking about selection etc. Another thing that annoying me is that multiple selection is enabled in fact. I can select couple of items in a scene w/o problem. But I still think that your proposal is the best way.

Comment: @folibis - Qt is huge, but it is more on the `bloated` than the `full-proof` end of the spectrum. A lot of times the provided functionality doesn't work the way you need it, other times it can even get in the way. Often the only way to get it your way is to do it yourself. That's why I went for QML despite the poor memory efficiency, it is much faster to do such things than the C++ graphics stack.

Comment: Has this sentiment changed in the last years? I currently have the very similar problem, of not being able to select a child, without the parent being deselected. My parent, on deselection, deletes these children, so I get nasty access violation errors.
I do not find any flags or calls to make to prevent deselection.
Currently I only see the options of implementing my own selection property, or perhaps find a way to trigger selection as a multiple selection, like it seems already possible by default, selecting Items in a Scene by holding down Ctrl....

Comment: I doubt it. The entire widget stacks has been a dead end since qt 5. Only some bug fixes, no other additions or improvements.